# Spring MVC - Redirect to login page in all tabs

Tags: java, javascript, session, spring-mvc

I have an ajax based site built in Spring MVC. On header it shows user that is logged in and a menu to browse to other pages. On click of menu page is changed via ajax call and menu/header remains the same. Here is a problem I am facing,

```
1- Logged in as user1
2- Click Profile Page to see its profile (via ajax loads fine)
3- Open another tab, open the same site, logged out and log in as user2
4- Come back to First Tab, click Profile Page again
This time it shows profile of User2 but on header/menu its still showing User1
```

How to implement this solution? or any better solution here?

```
-- As soon as a user is logged out, the web site should refresh to login page on all tabs where its opening on same browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you understand *why* the behavior is like this so I quickly explain it.

**Explanation**

Usually you have a single session per browser instance and not per tab. Hence, if you start browser X twice and load the application once in each instance you would not have this problem.

However, in a single browser instance the application loaded into tab 1 doesn't realize that you logged out and logged in with a different user in tab 2. It keeps a single session cookie per browser instance. Then if you interact with the application in tab 1 it finds the session cookie created when you logged in in tab 2 and uses it.

**Solution**

One solution (out of several) would be that you update the header every time you load one of the content pages. For this to work you either need to store the user information (id, name, etc.) in a cookie when the user logs in and read from the cookie when the content page is loaded. Or you send the user information along with every content page, of course it'd have to be hidden somewhere.

Comment: what about saving sessionid as cookie?

Comment: Ummhh, not sure I understand...The session ID _is_ stored in a cookie usually (1 per domain per browser).